# Find all submit buttons of submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to disable all submit type elements of a form once it's submitted, to avoid double clicking. But I only want the buttons within the submitted form to be disabled.

For example when clicking the `Submit` button, only the `Submit` button and the `Another submit to disable (same form)` should be disabled. The other submit elements should remain as they were.

The code below disables all submit elements.

```js
$(document).on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
 
    var submit_button = $(':submit');
    submit_button.prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="submit">Not part of submitted form (leave enabled)</button>
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Part of another Form (leave enabled)</button>
</form>

<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit">Another submit to disable (same form)</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you have to add a class or data attribute to these elements in order to select only the submit button you are interested in.

$('.submitbuttontobedisabled:submit')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `event.target` will refer to the `submited form`, so you can **find** all `submit buttons` inside that form using the `:submit` selector:

```
$(document).on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();              
    $(':submit',event.target).prop('disabled', true);

});
```

Check the **below snippet example**

```js
$(document).on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(':submit', event.target).prop('disabled', true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit">Not part of submitted form (leave enabled)</button>
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Part of another Form (leave enabled)</button>
</form>

<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit">Another submit to disable (same form)</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detect on form submit then search for the button[type=submit] in that form and disable them.

```
$('form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var submit_button = $(this).find('button[type="submit"]');
    submit_button.prop('disabled', true);
});
```